# Accordion not expanding

Tags: html, css

I'm making a dashboard and using old code from my project, when I copied it, the accordion doesn't expand (it should show + before opening, then - after opening with the content inside) am I doing something wrong, here's the code of mine

```
<div class="accordion">
    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="accordion-title">
            Moderation Commands
        </span>
        <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <p>p!help - See all bot comands</p>
</div>
```

sorry for the bad code placement on stackoverflow, I don't know how to do it

So here's the old project with the same code

Before opening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFapz.png

After opening : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc6nI.png

Here's the new project result with it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y54W.png

Comment: it could be that you did not include Bootstrap Javascript in the footer:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>

try insert this line in the footer and post a screenshot of the Console after you click the button

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, there's nothing on the console, I'm still new on programming either and kinda confused sometimes.

Comment: Did you also copy the CSS to the new project? Looks like there's no styling at all on the new accordeon.

Comment: I did add the css from old project to the new one (just the accordion one)